# Two languages being used at once in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, language

I recently made a clean install of Windows 10. I chose English (United States) as my language, and Latin American as my keyboard input. I deleted the other input language (English US) from the list in the first picture.
But as you can see, English US is still in the list, fully functional.

[image: Picture 1]

Also, this keeps happening. In the second picture, there is a picture of
the Unreal Engine main screen as an example: parts are in English and parts in Spanish.

Also, all the apps I get from the Store are in Spanish.
Why is this happening?

[image: Picture 2]

Comment: What you describe in the second screenshot with `Unreal Engine` main screen is a bug in their software.  Your other problem can be fixed by installing the US Keyboard then removing it again.

Comment: That's not the problem. That is just an example. I fixed that issue by the way, but the one with the keyboard layout persists.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and if what you're trying to do is to have windows, apps, browsers, etc. displayed in English and the input language to be Spanish you can do the following.

Set English with the US international keyboard as default and add Spanish (download the language package) and set US international keyboard as well.

Hope this works for you!